# Why is IN/EXISTS much slower than NOT IN/NOT EXISTS when comparing indexed columns? (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

Say I have 2 tables that share a column (same name & type) which is indexed in both.

Why is it that this comparison is instant while using `IN` or `EXISTS` (without `NOT`) takes a really long time?

```sql
    WITH cte1 AS (SELECT DISTINCT mycol FROM table1),
         cte2 AS (SELECT DISTINCT mycol FROM table2)
    SELECT mycol
    FROM cte1 a
    WHERE a.mycol NOT IN (SELECT mycol FROM cte1)

    -- OR "WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM cte2 b WHERE b.mycol = a.mycol)"
```

(Using PostgreSQL 13.4 and TimescaleDB 2.4.2. **This is a hypertable**, I'm not sure if it's related!)

EDIT: Running `EXPLAIN` the only difference I see is that the slow one is a "Merge Join" while the fast one is a "Merge Anti Join" *(and running it with EXPLAIN ANALYZE makes it slow too for some reason)*

Comment: In your example the `NOT` version will return no rows and the `IN/EXISTS` version every row where `mycol  is not null` - it is possible to determine the first one returns an empty resultset without even accessing any data, though I've no idea if that happens in your case.

Comment: Please use EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for your queries to get insights about the performance.

Comment: @Heikens with EXPLAINS I see that the only difference is that the slow one is a "Merge Join" while the fast one is a "Merge Anti Join". (And running it with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` makes it slow too)

Comment: Please show us the plans.  We might see more in them than you do.

Comment: EXPLAIN with ANALYE actually runs the query, and takes as long as that takes.

Answer (score 0):

For best performance, you can use `join` instead of `NOT IN` or `IN`. For example, instead of this query:

```
SELECT mycol
FROM cte1 a
WHERE a.mycol NOT IN (SELECT mycol FROM cte1)
```

you can use this:

```
SELECT mycol
FROM cte1 a
left join cte1 b on a.mycol = b.mycol 
WHERE b.mycol is null
```

`JOIN` will always give a performance higher than the `NOT IN` command